# Error message while developing Android Studio VPN Application

Tags: android, c++

The Following message appear While developing an Open VPN application :
07-04 21:33:34.998 20337-21875/pioneers.safwat.myvpn6 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OpenVPNManagementThread
                                                                        java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: pioneers.safwat.myvpn6.NativeUtils.jniclose:(I)V
                                                                            at pioneers.safwat.myvpn6.NativeUtils.jniclose(Native Method)
                                                                            at pioneers.safwat.myvpn6.OpenVpnManagementThread.protectFileDescriptor(OpenVpnManagementThread.java:175)
                                                                            at pioneers.safwat.myvpn6.OpenVpnManagementThread.processNeedCommand(OpenVpnManagementThread.java:387)
                                                                            at pioneers.safwat.myvpn6.OpenVpnManagementThread.processCommand(OpenVpnManagementThread.java:227)
                                                                            at pioneers.safwat.myvpn6.OpenVpnManagementThread.processInput(OpenVpnManagementThread.java:198)
                                                                            at pioneers.safwat.myvpn6.OpenVpnManagementThread.run(OpenVpnManagementThread.java:146)
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-04 21:33:35.288 20337-20337/pioneers.safwat.myvpn6 E/ActivityThread: Activity pioneers.safwat.myvpn6.MainActivity_vpn has leaked ServiceConnection pioneers.safwat.myvpn6.MainActivity_vpn$1@42537e00 that was originally bound here
                                                                        android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity pioneers.safwat.myvpn6.MainActivity_vpn has leaked ServiceConnection pioneers.safwat.myvpn6.MainActivity_vpn$1@42537e00 that was originally bound here
                                                                            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:979)
                                                                            at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:873)
                                                                            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1850)
                                                                            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1838)
                                                                            at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:503)
                                                                            at pioneers.safwat.myvpn6.MainActivity_vpn.onCreate(MainActivity_vpn.java:53)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)

Nativeutilis Class:

```
public class NativeUtils {
    public static native byte[] rsasign(byte[] input,int pkey) throws InvalidKeyException;
    public static native String[] getIfconfig() throws  IllegalArgumentException;
    static native void jniclose(int fdint);

    static {
    //  System.loadLibrary("opencv_java");
        System.loadLibrary("stlport_shared");
        System.loadLibrary("opvpnutil");
        System.loadLibrary("openvpn");
        System.loadLibrary("ssl");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        System.loadLibrary("crypto");
    }
}
```

The OpenVpnManagementThread Class:

```
   public class OpenVpnManagementThread implements Runnable, OpenVPNManagement {

    private static final String TAG = "Durai";
    private LocalSocket mSocket;
    private VpnProfile mProfile;
    private OpenVPNService mOpenVPNService;
    private LinkedList<FileDescriptor> mFDList = new LinkedList<FileDescriptor>();
    private LocalServerSocket mServerSocket;
    private boolean mReleaseHold = true;
    private boolean mWaitingForRelease = false;
    private long mLastHoldRelease = 0;

    private static final Vector<OpenVpnManagementThread> active = new Vector<OpenVpnManagementThread>();
    private LocalSocket mServerSocketLocal;

    private pauseReason lastPauseReason = pauseReason.noNetwork;

    public OpenVpnManagementThread(VpnProfile profile, OpenVPNService openVpnService) {
        mProfile = profile;
        mOpenVPNService = openVpnService;


        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(openVpnService);
        boolean managemeNetworkState = prefs.getBoolean("netchangereconnect", true);
        if (managemeNetworkState)
            mReleaseHold = false;

    }

    public boolean openManagementInterface(@NotNull Context c) {
        // Could take a while to open connection
        int tries = 8;

        String socketName = (c.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "mgmtsocket");
        // The mServerSocketLocal is transferred to the LocalServerSocket, ignore warning

        mServerSocketLocal = new LocalSocket();

        while (tries > 0 && !mServerSocketLocal.isConnected()) {
            try {
                mServerSocketLocal.bind(new LocalSocketAddress(socketName,
                        LocalSocketAddress.Namespace.FILESYSTEM));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // wait 300 ms before retrying
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                }

            }
            tries--;
        }

        try {

            mServerSocket = new LocalServerSocket(mServerSocketLocal.getFileDescriptor());
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            VpnStatus.logException(e);
        }
        return false;


    }

    public void managmentCommand(String cmd) {
        try {
            if (mSocket != null && mSocket.getOutputStream() != null) {
                mSocket.getOutputStream().write(cmd.getBytes());
                mSocket.getOutputStream().flush();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Ignore socket stack traces
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        //  mSocket.setSoTimeout(5); // Setting a timeout cannot be that bad

        String pendingInput = "";
        synchronized (active) {
            active.add(this);
        }

        try {
            // Wait for a client to connect
            mSocket = mServerSocket.accept();
            InputStream instream = mSocket.getInputStream();
            // Close the management socket after client connected

            mServerSocket.close();
            // Closing one of the two sockets also closes the other
            //mServerSocketLocal.close();

            while (true) {
                int numbytesread = instream.read(buffer);
                if (numbytesread == -1)
                    return;

                FileDescriptor[] fds = null;
                try {
                    fds = mSocket.getAncillaryFileDescriptors();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    VpnStatus.logException("Error reading fds from socket", e);
                }
                if (fds != null) {
                    Collections.addAll(mFDList, fds);
                }

                String input = new String(buffer, 0, numbytesread, "UTF-8");

                pendingInput += input;

                pendingInput = processInput(pendingInput);


            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (!e.getMessage().equals("socket closed") && !e.getMessage().equals("Connection reset by peer"))
                VpnStatus.logException(e);
        }
        synchronized (active) {
            active.remove(this);
        }
    }

    //! Hack O Rama 2000!
    private void protectFileDescriptor(FileDescriptor fd) {
        Exception exp;
        try {
            Method getInt = FileDescriptor.class.getDeclaredMethod("getInt$");
            int fdint = (Integer) getInt.invoke(fd);
            boolean result = mOpenVPNService.protect(fdint);
            if (!result)
                VpnStatus.logWarning("Could not protect VPN socket");
            NativeUtils.jniclose(fdint);
            return;
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            exp = e;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            exp = e;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            exp = e;
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            exp = e;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            exp = e;
        }

        Log.d("Openvpn", "Failed to retrieve fd from socket: " + fd);
        VpnStatus.logException("Failed to retrieve fd from socket (" + fd + ")", exp);
    }

    private String processInput(String pendingInput) {


        while (pendingInput.contains("\n")) {
            String[] tokens = pendingInput.split("\\r?\\n", 2);
            processCommand(tokens[0]);
            if (tokens.length == 1)
                // No second part, newline was at the end
                pendingInput = "";
            else
                pendingInput = tokens[1];
        }
        return pendingInput;
    }


    private void processCommand(String command) {
        //Log.i(TAG, "Line from managment" + command);


        if (command.startsWith(">") && command.contains(":")) {
            String[] parts = command.split(":", 2);
            String cmd = parts[0].substring(1);
            String argument = parts[1];


            if (cmd.equals("INFO")) {
                /* Ignore greeting from management */
                return;
            } else if (cmd.equals("PASSWORD")) {
                processPWCommand(argument);
            } else if (cmd.equals("HOLD")) {
                handleHold();
            } else if (cmd.equals("NEED-OK")) {
                processNeedCommand(argument);
            } else if (cmd.equals("BYTECOUNT")) {
                processByteCount(argument);
            } else if (cmd.equals("STATE")) {
                processState(argument);
            } else if (cmd.equals("PROXY")) {
                processProxyCMD(argument);
            } else if (cmd.equals("LOG")) {
                processLogMessage(argument);
            } else if (cmd.equals("RSA_SIGN")) {
                processSignCommand(argument);
            } else {
                VpnStatus.logWarning("MGMT: Got unrecognized command" + command);
                Log.i(TAG, "Got unrecognized command" + command);
            }
        } else if (command.startsWith("SUCCESS:")) {
            /* Ignore this kind of message too */
            return;
        } else if (command.startsWith("PROTECTFD: ")) {
            FileDescriptor fdtoprotect = mFDList.pollFirst();
            if (fdtoprotect != null)
                protectFileDescriptor(fdtoprotect);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Got unrecognized line from managment" + command);
            VpnStatus.logWarning("MGMT: Got unrecognized line from management:" + command);
        }
    }

    private void processLogMessage(String argument) {
        String[] args = argument.split(",", 4);
        Log.d("OpenVPN", argument);

        VpnStatus.LogLevel level;
        if (args[1].equals("I")) {
            level = VpnStatus.LogLevel.INFO;
        } else if (args[1].equals("W")) {
            level = VpnStatus.LogLevel.WARNING;
        } else if (args[1].equals("D")) {
            level = VpnStatus.LogLevel.VERBOSE;
        } else if (args[1].equals("F")) {
            level = VpnStatus.LogLevel.ERROR;
        } else {
            level = VpnStatus.LogLevel.INFO;
        }

        int ovpnlevel = Integer.parseInt(args[2]) & 0x0F;
        String msg = args[3];

        if (msg.startsWith("MANAGEMENT: CMD"))
            ovpnlevel = Math.max(4, ovpnlevel);

        VpnStatus.logMessageOpenVPN(level, ovpnlevel, msg);
    }

    private void handleHold() {
        if (mReleaseHold) {
            releaseHoldCmd();
        } else {
            mWaitingForRelease = true;
            VpnStatus.updateStatePause(lastPauseReason);

        }
    }

    private void releaseHoldCmd() {
        if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - mLastHoldRelease) < 5000) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            }

        }
        mWaitingForRelease = false;
        mLastHoldRelease = System.currentTimeMillis();
        managmentCommand("hold release\n");
        managmentCommand("bytecount " + mBytecountInterval + "\n");
        managmentCommand("state on\n");
    }

    public void releaseHold() {
        mReleaseHold = true;
        if (mWaitingForRelease)
            releaseHoldCmd();

    }

    private void processProxyCMD(String argument) {
        String[] args = argument.split(",", 3);
        SocketAddress proxyaddr = ProxyDetection.detectProxy(mProfile);


        if (args.length >= 2) {
            String proto = args[1];
            if (proto.equals("UDP")) {
                proxyaddr = null;
            }
        }

        if (proxyaddr instanceof InetSocketAddress) {
            InetSocketAddress isa = (InetSocketAddress) proxyaddr;

            VpnStatus.logInfo(R.string.using_proxy, isa.getHostName(), isa.getPort());

            String proxycmd = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "proxy HTTP %s %d\n", isa.getHostName(), isa.getPort());
            managmentCommand(proxycmd);
        } else {
            managmentCommand("proxy NONE\n");
        }

    }

    private void processState(String argument) {
        String[] args = argument.split(",", 3);
        String currentstate = args[1];

        if (args[2].equals(",,"))
            VpnStatus.updateStateString(currentstate, "");
        else
            VpnStatus.updateStateString(currentstate, args[2]);
    }


    private void processByteCount(String argument) {
        //   >BYTECOUNT:{BYTES_IN},{BYTES_OUT}
        int comma = argument.indexOf(',');
        long in = Long.parseLong(argument.substring(0, comma));
        long out = Long.parseLong(argument.substring(comma + 1));
        VpnStatus.updateByteCount(in, out);
    }
    private void processNeedCommand(String argument) {
        int p1 = argument.indexOf('\'');
        int p2 = argument.indexOf('\'', p1 + 1);
        String needed = argument.substring(p1 + 1, p2);
        String extra = argument.split(":", 2)[1];
        String status = "ok";
        if (needed.equals("PROTECTFD")) {
            FileDescriptor fdtoprotect = mFDList.pollFirst();
            protectFileDescriptor(fdtoprotect);
        } else if (needed.equals("DNSSERVER")) {
            mOpenVPNService.addDNS(extra);
        } else if (needed.equals("DNSDOMAIN")) {
            mOpenVPNService.setDomain(extra);
        } else if (needed.equals("ROUTE")) {
            String[] routeparts = extra.split(" ");

            if (routeparts.length == 5) {
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Assert.assertEquals("dev", routeparts[3]);
                mOpenVPNService.addRoute(routeparts[0], routeparts[1], routeparts[2], routeparts[4]);
            } else if (routeparts.length >= 3) {
                mOpenVPNService.addRoute(routeparts[0], routeparts[1], routeparts[2], null);
            } else {
                VpnStatus.logError("Unrecognized ROUTE cmd:" + Arrays.toString(routeparts) + " | " + argument);
            }

        } else if (needed.equals("ROUTE6")) {
            String[] routeparts = extra.split(" ");
            mOpenVPNService.addRoutev6(routeparts[0], routeparts[1]);
        } else if (needed.equals("IFCONFIG")) {
            String[] ifconfigparts = extra.split(" ");
            int mtu = Integer.parseInt(ifconfigparts[2]);
            mOpenVPNService.setLocalIP(ifconfigparts[0], ifconfigparts[1], mtu, ifconfigparts[3]);
        } else if (needed.equals("IFCONFIG6")) {
            mOpenVPNService.setLocalIPv6(extra);

        } else if (needed.equals("PERSIST_TUN_ACTION")) {
            // check if tun cfg stayed the same
            status = mOpenVPNService.getTunReopenStatus();
        } else if (needed.equals("OPENTUN")) {
            if (sendTunFD(needed, extra))
                return;
            else
                status = "cancel";
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unkown needok command " + argument);
            return;
        }
        String cmd = String.format("needok '%s' %s\n", needed, status);
        managmentCommand(cmd);
    }
    private boolean sendTunFD(String needed, String extra) {
        Exception exp;
        if (!extra.equals("tun")) {
            VpnStatus.logError(String.format("Device type %s requested, but only tun is possible with the Android API, sorry!", extra));
            return false;
        }
        ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = mOpenVPNService.openTun();
        if (pfd == null)
            return false;

        Method setInt;
        int fdint = pfd.getFd();
        try {
            setInt = FileDescriptor.class.getDeclaredMethod("setInt$", int.class);
            FileDescriptor fdtosend = new FileDescriptor();
            setInt.invoke(fdtosend, fdint);
            FileDescriptor[] fds = {fdtosend};
            mSocket.setFileDescriptorsForSend(fds);
            String cmd = String.format("needok '%s' %s\n", needed, "ok");
            managmentCommand(cmd);
            mSocket.setFileDescriptorsForSend(null);
            pfd.close();
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            exp = e;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            exp = e;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            exp = e;
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            exp = e;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            exp = e;
        }
        VpnStatus.logException("Could not send fd over socket", exp);
        return false;
    }

    private void processPWCommand(String argument) {
        String needed;
        try {

            int p1 = argument.indexOf('\'');
            int p2 = argument.indexOf('\'', p1 + 1);
            needed = argument.substring(p1 + 1, p2);
            if (argument.startsWith("Verification Failed")) {
                proccessPWFailed(needed, argument.substring(p2 + 1));
                return;
            }
        } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException sioob) {
            VpnStatus.logError("Could not parse management Password command: " + argument);
            return;
        }
        String pw = null;

        if (needed.equals("Private Key")) {
            pw = mProfile.getPasswordPrivateKey();
        } else if (needed.equals("Auth")) {
            String usercmd = String.format("username '%s' %s\n",
                    needed, VpnProfile.openVpnEscape(mProfile.mUsername));
            managmentCommand(usercmd);
            pw = mProfile.getPasswordAuth();
        }
        if (pw != null) {
            String cmd = String.format("password '%s' %s\n", needed, VpnProfile.openVpnEscape(pw));
            managmentCommand(cmd);
        } else {
            VpnStatus.logError(String.format("Openvpn requires Authentication type '%s' but no password/key information available", needed));
        }
    }

    private void proccessPWFailed(String needed, String args) {
        VpnStatus.updateStateString("AUTH_FAILED", needed + args,R.string.state_auth_failed, VpnStatus.ConnectionStatus.LEVEL_AUTH_FAILED);
    }
    private static boolean stopOpenVPN() {
        synchronized (active) {
            boolean sendCMD = false;
            for (OpenVpnManagementThread mt : active) {
                mt.managmentCommand("signal SIGINT\n");
                sendCMD = true;
                try {
                    if (mt.mSocket != null)
                        mt.mSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
            return sendCMD;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void networkChange() {
        if (!mWaitingForRelease)
            managmentCommand("network-change\n");
    }

    public void signalusr1() {
        mReleaseHold = false;

        if (!mWaitingForRelease)
            managmentCommand("signal SIGUSR1\n");
        else
            VpnStatus.updateStatePause(lastPauseReason);
    }

    public void reconnect() {
        signalusr1();
        releaseHold();
    }
    private void processSignCommand(String b64data) {
        String signed_string = mProfile.getSignedData(b64data);
        if (signed_string == null) {
            managmentCommand("rsa-sig\n");
            managmentCommand("\nEND\n");
            stopOpenVPN();
            return;
        }
        managmentCommand("rsa-sig\n");
        managmentCommand(signed_string);
        managmentCommand("\nEND\n");
    }
    @Override
    public void pause(pauseReason reason) {
        lastPauseReason = reason;
        signalusr1();
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        releaseHold();
        /* Reset the reason why we are disconnected */
        lastPauseReason = pauseReason.noNetwork;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean stopVPN() {
        return stopOpenVPN();
    }
}
```

The MainActivity_vpn Class:

```
public class MainActivity_vpn extends Activity {
protected OpenVPNService mService;
boolean mBound = false;
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                   IBinder service) {
        OpenVPNService.LocalBinder binder = (OpenVPNService.LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mService =null;
        mBound = false;
    }
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_vpn);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), OpenVPNService.class);
    intent.setAction(OpenVPNService.START_SERVICE);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("CONNECTION_CHANGE"));
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.settingsmenu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (Constants.isVPNConnected){
        // disable connect button if VPN is connected
        menu.getItem(0).setEnabled(false);
        // enable disconnect button if VPN is connected
        menu.getItem(1).setEnabled(true);
    } else{
        // enable connect button if VPN is disconnected
        menu.getItem(0).setEnabled(true);
        // disable disconnect button if VPN is disconnected
        menu.getItem(1).setEnabled(false);
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_startvpn:
            configureAndStartVpn() ;
            return true ;
        case R.id.action_stopvpn:
            stopVPN() ;
            return true ;
        case R.id.action_removeProfile:
            removeProfile();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
private void removeProfile() {

    final ProfileManager pm = ProfileManager.getInstance(MainActivity_vpn.this) ;
    final VpnProfile profile = pm.getProfileByName(Constants.VPN_PROFILE_NAME) ;

    if (profile != null) {
                        stopVPN() ;
                        pm.removeProfile(getApplicationContext(),profile);
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity_vpn.this,"The VPN Configuration is deleted", duration);
                        toast.show();
    } else {
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity_vpn.this,"There are no VPN Configurations to delete", duration);toast.show();
    }
}
private void stopVPN() {
    try{
        ProfileManager.setConntectedVpnProfileDisconnected(MainActivity_vpn.this);
        if(mService.getManagement()!=null)
            mService.getManagement().stopVPN();
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
    }
}
private void configureAndStartVpn() {
    try {
                EditText Et_Ovpn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_ovpn);

                String retVal = Et_Ovpn.getText().toString();

                if (retVal != null && retVal.trim().length()>0) {

                    byte[] buffer = retVal.getBytes() ;

                    VpnProfile vp = saveProfile(buffer) ;

                    if (vp != null) {
                        startVPN(vp) ;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity_vpn.this,"Connecting using the last vpn configuration", duration);
                    toast.show();
                    startVPN();
                }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace() ;
    }
}
private VpnProfile saveProfile(byte [] data) {

    ConfigParser cp = new ConfigParser();
    try {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
        cp.parseConfig(isr);
        VpnProfile vp = cp.convertProfile();
        ProfileManager vpl = ProfileManager.getInstance(this);
        vp.mName = Constants.VPN_PROFILE_NAME ;
        vpl.addProfile(vp);
        vpl.saveProfile(this, vp);
        vpl.saveProfileList(this);
        return vp ;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return null ;
    }
}
public void startVPN(VpnProfile vp) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LaunchVPN.class);
    intent.putExtra(LaunchVPN.EXTRA_KEY, vp.getUUID().toString());
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startActivity(intent);
}
private void startVPN() {

    ProfileManager pm = ProfileManager.getInstance(this) ;
    VpnProfile profile = pm.getProfileByName(Constants.VPN_PROFILE_NAME) ;

    if (profile == null) {
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity_vpn.this,"There are no VPN Configurations.So paste the .OVPN and try", duration);
        toast.show();
        return ;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,LaunchVPN.class);
    intent.putExtra(LaunchVPN.EXTRA_KEY, profile.getUUID().toString());
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startActivity(intent);
}
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        stopVPN();
        startVPN();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didn't take in my consideration that declarations of native methods should placed in the class with the same name and package as in donor project.
once i change the package name for native method the problem solved

Answer (score 0):

From your log i saw this line:

```
MainActivity_vpn has leaked ServiceConnection
```

In your activity `OnCreate` you're binding to service but you never unbind.
Add this to you're `onDestroy` method in your `MainActivity`:

```
    if (mServiceConn != null) {
      unbindService(mServiceConn);
    }
```

Also, see this:
[JNI- java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566127/jni-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-native-method-not-found)

I think that you should remove the static from your methods signature

Comment: MainActivity_vpn has leaked ServiceConnection disappeared now, But the rest of the error (Native method not found: pioneers.safwat.myvpn6.NativeUtils.jniclose:(I)V) still exist , i think the problem in The loading library in the nativeutils class

Comment: I think that you're right. Maybe you initialized it wrong or something a like

Comment: See may additional part of the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
private VpnProfile saveProfile(byte [] data) {

ConfigParser cp = new ConfigParser();
try {
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
    cp.parseConfig(isr);
```

*Here the ConfigParser() is not a public class so that you can create an instance of it.*

[This is from the android SDK 29](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eiglt.png)