# My app in Android Studio keeps crashing when I run it

Tags: android, opencv

I was following an OpenCV Installation and SIFT Tutorial for Android Studio. I did everything exactly as the video tutorial said for me to do, and I've probably redone it 10 times now on 3 different computers, but I always get the same problem. The gradle will build without a problem, so there aren't any errors in the code, but when I run the app on an emulator, the app will crash immediately.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.anita.opencvtestattempt3"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(':libraries:opencv')
}
```

and here is the logcat when I run the app:

```
07-17 16:07:51.309 4369-4369/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already 
on)
07-17 16:07:51.309 4369-4369/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using 
defaults: x86
07-17 16:07:51.404 4369-4369/com.example.anita.opencvtestattempt3 
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
07-17 16:07:51.422 4369-4369/com.example.anita.opencvtestattempt3 
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-17 16:07:51.423 4369-4369/com.example.anita.opencvtestattempt3 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.anita.opencvtestattempt3, PID: 4369

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: file offset for the library 
"/data/app/com.example.anita.opencvtestattempt3-2/lib/x86/libopencv_java.so" 
>= file size: 0 >= 0

at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:977)

at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1530)

at com.example.anita.opencvtestattempt3.MainActivity.<clinit>
(MainActivity.java:18)

at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)

at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)

at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2538)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)

at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsC
aller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: Have a look here, maybe something will work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037966/android-ndk-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-findlibrary-returned-null

Comment: verify the "opencv.so" file has been created by the build. verify that the .so is included in your apk with the path indicated by the "dlopen" stmt.